# Keras model doest not provide same results after converting into tensorflow-js model

Tags: javascript, python, keras, tensorflowjs

Keras model performs as expected in python but after converting the model the results are different on the same data.

I tried updating the keras and tensorflow-js version but still the same issue.

Python code for testing:

```
import keras
import cv2
model = keras.models.load_model("keras_model.h5")
img = cv2.imread("test_image.jpg")

def preprocessing_img(img):
    img = cv2.resize(img, (50,50))
    x = np.array(img)
    image = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
    return image/255

prediction_array= model.predict(preprocessing_img(img))
print(prediction_array)
print(np.argmax(prediction_array))
```

Results:
[[1.9591815e-16 1.0000000e+00 3.8602989e-18 3.2472009e-19 5.8910814e-11]]
1

These results are correct.

Javascript Code:

tfjs version:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@0.13.5">
</script>
```

preprocessing_img method and prediction in js:

```
function preprocessing_img(img)
  {
    let tensor = tf.fromPixels(img)
    const resized = tf.image.resizeBilinear(tensor, [50, 50]).toFloat()
    const offset = tf.scalar(255.0);
    const normalized = tf.scalar(1.0).sub(resized.div(offset));
    const batched = normalized.expandDims(0)

    return batched

  }

const pred = model.predict(preprocessing_img(imgEl)).dataSync()
const class_index = tf.argMax(pred);
```

In this case the results are not same and the last index in the pred array is 1 90% of the time.

I think there is something wrong with the preprocessing method of image in javascript since i am not an expert in javascript or am i missing something in javascript part?

Comment: Did you make any progress with this? I am experiencing the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

It has to do with the image used for the prediction. The image needs to have completely loaded before the prediction.

```
imEl.onload = function (){
 const pred = 
 model.predict(preprocessing_img(imgEl)).dataSync()
 const class_index = tf.argMax(pred);
}
```