# Different model.predict() result after converting to Tensorflow.js from Python

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow.js

This is a new question but based on the answer in [I'm having trouble with the transition of Tensorflow Python to Tensorflow.js in regards to image preprocessing. What am I missing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61862503/im-having-trouble-with-the-transition-of-tensorflow-python-to-tensorflow-js-in)

using the same Tensorflow model and image with Python Tensorflow and Tensorflow.js I get different results.

**Python**

```
img = image.load_img(single_coin, target_size = (100, 100))
array = image.img_to_array(img)
x = np.expand_dims(array, axis=0)
vimage = x/255
prediction =model.predict(vimage)
print(prediction[0])
```

**Correct Result**
[0.04473673 0.04597054 0.04576655 0.04592451 0.04503974 0.04592359
 0.04571134 0.04524434 0.04691761 0.04520368 0.04635021 0.04504307
 0.04530064 0.04513143 0.04529772 0.04485165 0.04539195 0.04510813
 0.04511049 0.04507154 0.04535922 0.04554531]

**Javascript**

```
let pred = await model.predict(preprocess(coin_img)).data();

function preprocess(img)
{
   let tensor = tf.browser.fromPixels(img);
   const resized = tf.image.resizeBilinear(tensor, [100, 100]).toFloat();
   const offset = tf.scalar(255.0);
   const normalized = resized.div(offset);
   const batched = normalized.expandDims(0);
   return batched;
}
```

**Wrong Result**
[0.04504432901740074, 0.04557133838534355, 0.04549449682235718, 0.04559708759188652, 0.045041460543870926, 0.04586553946137428, 0.04559847712516785, 0.0453043170273304, 
0.04624791815876961, 0.04556102305650711, 0.046446215361356735, 0.045481305569410324, 
0.045504890382289886, 0.04509727284312248, 0.045254919677972794, 0.044636815786361694, 
0.04570333659648895, 0.045125190168619156, 0.04540202021598816, 0.04514292627573013, 
0.0454869344830513, 0.04539225250482559]

I'm wondering if I'm having the issue outlined in [Keras model doest not provide same results after converting into tensorflow-js model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56617528/keras-model-doest-not-provide-same-results-after-converting-into-tensorflow-js-m) but I'm unsure. I tried the suggestion with no success.

or am I making a mistake somewhere--I think I have the JS image preprocessing code matching the Python but may be not...?

**------------------- UPDATE -------------------**

I added a great deal more images (>3000) as well as filled out the classes (92 in total). Python is working great, I can't get it to break.  But on the Tensorflow.js side I can't get it to provide a consistent prediction.  The answer is usually the second or third option (versus the first).

Here is a comparison of the prediction for all 92 classes for the same image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7IlAS.jpg

Model was saved as:

```
Python as:
   model.save(filepath1)

Tensorflow.js as:
   tfjs.converters.save_keras_model(model, filepath2)
```

**I'm just at a loss for how to debug this or what to try next.  Any pointers on a direction for me to pursue would be very helpful. As background, here is how I created the model**

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH, 3)))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(128, (3,3), activation="relu"))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2)))
model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(92, activation='softmax'))

model.summary()

Model: "sequential_2"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d_8 (Conv2D)            (None, 248, 248, 64)      1792      
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_8 (MaxPooling2 (None, 124, 124, 64)      0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_9 (Conv2D)            (None, 122, 122, 64)      36928     
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_9 (MaxPooling2 (None, 61, 61, 64)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_10 (Conv2D)           (None, 59, 59, 128)       73856     
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_10 (MaxPooling (None, 29, 29, 128)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_11 (Conv2D)           (None, 27, 27, 128)       147584    
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_11 (MaxPooling (None, 13, 13, 128)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_2 (Flatten)          (None, 21632)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_4 (Dense)              (None, 512)               11076096  
_________________________________________________________________
dense_5 (Dense)              (None, 92)                47196     
=================================================================
Total params: 11,383,452
Trainable params: 11,383,452
Non-trainable params: 0


model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer=tensorflow.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(lr=1e-4),
              metrics=['acc'])

history = model.fit(
      train_batches,
      steps_per_epoch=train_batches.samples/train_batches.batch_size ,
      epochs=30,
      validation_data=valid_batches,
      validation_steps=valid_batches.samples/valid_batches.batch_size,
      verbose=1)

**Here are the last few Epochs:**

75/75 [==============================] - 28s 379ms/step - loss: 0.0786 - acc: 0.9808 - val_loss: 0.4787 - val_acc: 0.8865
Epoch 28/30
75/75 [==============================] - 29s 381ms/step - loss: 0.0714 - acc: 0.9825 - val_loss: 0.5362 - val_acc: 0.9005
Epoch 29/30
75/75 [==============================] - 28s 378ms/step - loss: 0.1034 - acc: 0.9767 - val_loss: 0.9660 - val_acc: 0.8616
Epoch 30/30
75/75 [==============================] - 29s 387ms/step - loss: 0.0720 - acc: 0.9829 - val_loss: 0.5771 - val_acc: 0.8942
```

**I'm using the same prediction code at the top of my original post above for both Python and Tensorflow.js - nothing changed there**

Comment: Both results are not far off each other. There can be a slight difference in the tensor generated from the image on python and js. Consequently, there can be a slight difference in the prediction. But this should not affect the overall prediction. And looking at your prediction, I won't say that the js prediction is a wrong one. All the prediction seems to be around 0.045 be it in python or in js

Comment: got it.  thank you.  I'm about to get serious about the data and the hidden layers so I'll have a great deal more to compare in a couple weeks.  thank you for responding so I don't spending any more time worrying about it right now.

Comment: I added data and more classes.  Seems I'm making the Tensorflow.js side worse but Python side is staying stable.  I added the update to the original post above. Any pointers on what to try next would be great.  I'm pointing in the dark right now.

Comment: OK, I figured it out after reading some of your other posts.  It's a browser issue dealing with images differently.  I'll work around this by not letting the browser deal with the image.  Your other posts/answers are brilliant Ed.